# Django mock unit test form filefield

Tags: django, forms, mocking, filefield, django-unittest

I have a form that I want to unittest:

**app/form.py**

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()
```

**app/test.py**

```
class MyFormTest(TestCase):

    def test_my_form(self):
        file_mock = MagicMock(spec=File)
        form = MyForm({'file':file_mock})
        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

How can i unit test this form using mock or other was? If possible I would like to test this form using mock. How can I patch and mock test it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this solution from another source:

```
form = MyForm(files={'file':file_mock})
```

or

```
file_dict = {'file': SimpleUploadedFile(upload_file.name, upload_file.read())}
form = MyForm(files=file_dict)
```

This did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
 ...
def test_form(self):
        upload_file = open('path/to/file', 'rb')
        file_dict = {'file': SimpleUploadedFile(upload_file.name, upload_file.read())}
        form = MyForm(file_dict)
        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

Comment: This is not working. This shows asserts false is not true.
It is even reading data from the file but the form validation is failing